# Why did Krishna and Rama even care about what others think about him?

Tags: krishna, rama

Krishna proved his innocence In the [following](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp106.htm) context

> Sons of Satwata. Bhoja princes of Mrittikávatí. Súrya the friend of
>   Satrájit: appears to him in a bodily form: gives him the Syamantaka
>   gem: its brilliance and marvellous properties. Satrájit gives it to
>   Prasena, who is killed by a lion: the lion killed by the bear
>   Jámbavat. Krishńa suspected of killing Prasena, goes to look for him
>   in the forests: traces the bear to his cave: fights with him for the
>   jewel: the contest prolonged: supposed by his companions to be slain:
>   he overthrows Jámbavat, and marries his daughter Jámbavatí: returns
>   with her and the jewel to Dwáraká: restores the jewel to Satrájit, and
>   marries his daughter Satyabhámá. Satrájit murdered by Śatadhanwan:
>   avenged by Krishńa. The quarrel between Krishńa and Balaráma. Akrúra
>   possessed of the jewel: leaves Dwáraká. Public calamities. Meeting of
>   the Yádavas. The story of Akrúra's birth: he is invited to return: accused
>   by Krishńa of having the Syamantaka jewel: produces it in full
>   assembly: it remains in his charge: Krishńa acquitted of having
>   purloined it.

Similarly, Rama asked to prove the innocence of Sita.

Why did they even care about others opinions if they are not involved in guilt?  Are there any references stating that one should prove innocence or to care others opinion on us? Or is it only valid for Kshatriyas to care what others think about others opinion on them?

Comment: They want to set examples on how to lead a human life

Comment: Means that they are saying to humans to care about what others think?

Comment: The jewel problem is the time period where Shani dasa was running for Krishna as per some references I've seen!

Comment: Not like that. In Lord Rama case, he was a king and he led by example as king.

Comment: @hanugm "Krishna proved his innocence" - first of all this innocence word is inappropriate...it seems u hv already judged Krishna...and it should be understood that King or his family should clear such doubts...even today if some allegation is there on PM don't u think a idle PM should not clear such doubts?

Comment: @YDS I mean Krishna didn't steal it. So he is not involved in that theft. In that sense, I used such word. If PM involves in proving such things, then it's time waste for him.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS you r answering why allegation was put on Krishna... One more reason for that is Krishna saw moon on Ganesha chaturthi.. Ganesha cursed moon that whoever sees it on Ganesh chaturthi will suffer from false allegation....but question is why Krishna gave importance to such allegation and answers to this will be opinion based I think...

Answer (score 3):

> यद्यदाचरति श्रेष्ठस्तत्तदेवेतरो जन: | स यत्प्रमाणं कुरुते
>   लोकस्तदनुवर्तते || 3-21||
>
> yad yad ācharati śhreṣhṭhas tat tad evetaro janaḥ sa yat pramāṇaṁ
>   kurute lokas tad anuvartate
>
> You should also perform your work to set an example for the good of
>   the world. Whatever actions great persons perform, common people
>   follow. Whatever standards they set, all the world pursues.

Humanity is inspired by the ideals that they see in the lives of great people. Such leaders inspire society by their example and become shining beacons for the masses to follow. Leaders of society thus have a moral responsibility to set lofty examples for inspiring the rest of the population by their words, deeds, and character. When noble leaders are in the forefront, the rest of society naturally gets uplifted in morality, selflessness, and spiritual strength. But in times when there is a vacuum of principled leadership, the rest of society has no standards to pursue and slumps into self-centeredness, moral bankruptcy, and spiritual lassitude. Hence, great personalities should always act in an exemplary manner to set the standard for the world. Even though they themselves may have risen to the transcendental platform, and may not need to perform prescribed Vedic duties, by doing so, they inspire others to perform prescribed Vedic actions.

Comment: Your quote is fine but as OP says, 'Rama asked to prove the innocence of Sita' - so is that what the masses need to follow?

Comment: Yes, the problem today is everybody wants to be trustable by belief not by proving/doing things. It is hard to accept that "it is totally fine if people are not trusting and asking for extra actions to prove yourself", it's human nature, Rama gracefully accepted that and did whatever need to be done.

Comment: 'Rama gracefully accepted that' - ha ha, but for the masses, that's not the issue. Do women (or whoever is on the receiving end) also 'gracefully accept' abandonment by their husbands or take a fire test to prove something or the other?

Comment: Yes, If she trust and love her husband.

Comment: Rama took priksha of Sita not coz he has doubt on Sita. But instead he took so no other can lift finger on Sita. Besides one more reason was there, Rama need to take Sita back from Agni Deva. Actually, only clone of Sita was abducted by Ravana, and original Sita was in protection of Agni Deva. When Laksham came to know Rama was going to take agni priksha then Lakshman started protest against it. Then Rama told him truth that he just wanna his Sita back from Agni deva, that's why this leela is important.